# Java prediction error Random not working?

Tags: java, for-loop, random

Hello I have been working on a program that predicts numbers. I have went through the code several times now and edited it. For some reason teamOneScored is ALWAYS higher than teamTwoScored. This does not make any sense to me.

What is the error that is occurring?

Here is my CompareEngine Class:

```
 package compare;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Random;

 import data.Main;

 public class CompareEngine 
 {
     public static void Comparison(int firstTeamTotal, int secondTeamTotal, 
     int[] firstPositionAmount, int[] secondPositionAmount, int[] 
      firstPosition, int[] secondPosition)
 {
    System.out.println("             Comparisons:");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(Main.firstTeam + "           vs.           " + Main.secondTeam);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(firstTeamTotal + "             Total " + "               " + secondTeamTotal);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(firstPosition[0]-1+"-"+firstPosition[1]+"-"+firstPosition[2] + "         Formation            " + (secondPosition[0]-1) +"-"+secondPosition[1]+"-"+secondPosition[2]);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(firstPosition[0] + "             Defenders " + "               " + secondPosition[0]);
    System.out.println(firstPositionAmount[0] + "         Defense Total " + "           " + secondPositionAmount[0]);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(firstPosition[1] + "            Midfielders " + "              " + secondPosition[1]);
    System.out.println(firstPositionAmount[1] + "         Midfield Total " + "          " + secondPositionAmount[1]);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(firstPosition[2] + "              Attackers " + "              " + secondPosition[2]);
    System.out.println(firstPositionAmount[2] + "           Attack Total " + "           " + secondPositionAmount[2]);      
}

public static void RunGame(int firstTeamTotal, int secondTeamTotal, int[] firstPositionAmount, 
        int[] secondPositionAmount, int[] firstPosition, int[] secondPosition) throws IOException
{
    int depth;

    System.out.println("What depth do you want to run?");
    depth = Main.read.nextInt();

    int firstShotCount = 0;
    int secondShotCount = 0;

    int firstDefense = firstPositionAmount[0] + firstPositionAmount[1]/2;
    int secondDefense = secondPositionAmount[0] + secondPositionAmount[1]/2;

    int firstAttack = firstPositionAmount[2] + firstPositionAmount[1]/2;
    int secondAttack = secondPositionAmount[2] + secondPositionAmount[2]/2;


    while(firstAttack*3 > secondDefense)
    {
        firstShotCount = firstShotCount + 1;
        firstAttack = firstAttack - 5;
    }

    while(secondAttack*3 > firstDefense)
    {

        secondShotCount = secondShotCount + 1;
        secondAttack = secondAttack - 5;
    }

    System.out.println(firstShotCount);
    System.out.println(secondShotCount);

    PossessionControl(Main.firstTeam, Main.secondTeam);

    int[] teamOneScored = new int[99];
    int[] teamTwoScored = new int[99];
    int[] oneShotOn = new int[99];
    int[] twoShotOn = new int[99];
    int[] OnePossession = new int[99];
    int[] TwoPossession = new int[99];

    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; firstShotCount >= x; x++)
        {
            int shot = random.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;

            if (shot > 8)
            {
                teamOneScored[i] = teamOneScored[i] + 1;
            }

            if (shot > 4)
            {
                oneShotOn[i] = oneShotOn[i] + 1;
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; secondShotCount >= y; y++)
        {
            int shot = random.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;

            if (shot > 8)
            {
                teamTwoScored[i] = teamTwoScored[i] + 1;
            }

            if (shot > 4)
            {
                twoShotOn[i] = twoShotOn[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(teamOneScored[i] + ":" + teamTwoScored[i]);
    }
}

static File firstDataFile = new File("src/playerdata/" + Main.firstTeam);
static File secondDataFile = new File("src/playerdata/" + Main.secondTeam);

static int teamOnePossessionTotal = 0;
static int teamTwoPossessionTotal = 0;

public static void PossessionControl(String firstTeam, String secondTeam) throws IOException
{       

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(firstDataFile));
    String line = "";
    for(int i = 1; i+1 < 13; i++) 
    {
        line = br1.readLine();
        teamOnePossessionTotal = teamOnePossessionTotal + PossessionStatTotal(line);
    }
    br1.close();

    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(secondDataFile));

    for(int i = 1; i+1 < 13; i++) 
    {
        line = br2.readLine();
        teamTwoPossessionTotal = teamTwoPossessionTotal + PossessionStatTotal(line);
    }
    br2.close();
}

public static int PossessionStatTotal(String line)
{
    int value = 0;
    String[] stats = line.split("-");
    String position = stats[1];

    if(!(position.equals("GK")))
    {       
        String passing = stats[5];
        String positioning = stats[7];
        String ballControl = stats[9];
        value = (int) ((int) (Integer.valueOf(passing)*.5) + Integer.valueOf(positioning)*.2 + Integer.valueOf(ballControl)*.1);
    }

    return value;
}   
}
```

Here is my Main Class:

```
 package data;


 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main 
 {
public static String currentTeam;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    compareTeams();
    //setOveralls();
}

public static void setOveralls() throws IOException
{
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Which team do you like?");
    currentTeam = read.nextLine();
    read.close();

    PlayerOverall.eraseOverallFile();
    PlayerOverall.getPlayerInfo(13, currentTeam);

}

public static String firstTeam;
public static String secondTeam;
public static Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void compareTeams() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("What is the first team?");
    firstTeam = read.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the second team?");
    secondTeam = read.nextLine();

    compare.CompareTeams.compare(firstTeam, secondTeam);
}

}
```

Here is the PlayerOverall Class, this just determines their Overall.

```
 package data;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;


 public class PlayerOverall 
 {
//NOTE TO SELF -- CHANGE OUT OF HARD CODE   VVVVVVVVVVV
static File dataFile = new File("src/playerdata/" + Main.currentTeam);
static File overallFile = new File("src/overalls/" + Main.currentTeam);


public static String getPlayerInfo(int numLine, String currentTeam) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));
    String line = "";
    for(int i = 1; i+1 < numLine; i++) 
    {
        line = br.readLine();
        evaluatePlayer(line);
    }
    br.close();
    return line; 
}

public static void evaluatePlayer(String line) throws IOException
{ 
    String[] stats = line.split("-");
    String position = stats[1];

    int overall = 0;

    if(position.equals("GK"))
    {
        int height = Integer.parseInt(stats[2]);
        int diving = Integer.parseInt(stats[3]);
        int catching = Integer.parseInt(stats[4]);
        int shooting = Integer.parseInt(stats[5]);
        int reflexes = Integer.parseInt(stats[6]);
        int positioning = Integer.parseInt(stats[7]);

        overall = (int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) (height*.05) + diving*.2) + catching*.2) + shooting*.1) + reflexes*.2) + positioning*.25); 
        setOverall(position, overall);
        //OVERALL WORKS CORRECT NOW DO THE ADDITION OF OVERALL TO THE FILE!!
    }
    else
    {
        int speed = Integer.parseInt(stats[2]);
        int acceleration = Integer.parseInt(stats[3]);
        int distance = Integer.parseInt(stats[4]);
        int passing = Integer.parseInt(stats[5]);
        int shooting = Integer.parseInt(stats[6]);
        int positioning = Integer.parseInt(stats[7]);
        int defending = Integer.parseInt(stats[8]);
        int ballControll = Integer.parseInt(stats[9]);

        if(position.equals("LB") || position.equals("RB"))
        {
            overall = (int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) (speed*.2) + acceleration*.2) + distance*.1) + passing*.1) + shooting*.1) + positioning*.15) + defending*.15) + ballControll*.1); 
        }
        else if(position.equals("CB"))
        {
            overall = (int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) (speed*.095) + acceleration*.1) + distance*.1) + passing*.1) + shooting*.05) + positioning*.2) + defending*.3) + ballControll*.1); 
        }
        else if(position.equals("CM"))
        {
            overall = (int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) (speed*.05) + acceleration*.05) + distance*.15) + passing*.2) + shooting*.1) + positioning*.2) + defending*.1) + ballControll*.1) + 10; 
        }
        else if(position.equals("LM") || position.equals("RM"))
        {
            overall = (int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) (speed*.2) + acceleration*.2) + distance*.1) + passing*.1) + shooting*.133) + positioning*.1) + defending*.033) + ballControll*.133) + 5; 
        }
        else if(position.equals("ST"))
        {
            int stength = Integer.parseInt(stats[10]);
            overall = (int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) ((int) (speed*.133) + acceleration*.133) + distance*.033) + passing*.05) + shooting*.225) + positioning*.225) + defending*.0) + ballControll*.1) + stength*.1) + 5; 
        }

        setOverall(position, overall);
    }   
}

public static void setOverall(String position, int overall) throws IOException
{
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(overallFile, true)) 
    {

        fw.append(position + "-" + overall +"\n");
    }

}

public static void eraseOverallFile() throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(overallFile);
    fw.write("");
    fw.close();
}
}
```

The files I am getting for are just regular files. They look like this:

```
 Lukas Hradecky-GK-63-81-81-74-89-82
 Jetro Willems-LB-83-86-80-79-76-72-76-81
 David Abraham-CB-76-83-68-74-70-76-80-61
 Simon Falette-CB-60-71-77-57-50-74-84-56
 Timmy Chandler-RB-80-76-83-74-68-71-77-74
 Marco Fabian-CM-70-76-75-78-80-77-36-85
 Jonathan De Guzman-CM-78-79-70-78-80-78-51-83
 Mijat Gacinovic-RM-78-78-74-70-68-69-61-81
 Ante Rebic-LM-76-79-71-62-78-72-40-75
 Sebastien Haller-ST-75-79-73-64-77-77-35-79-91
 Kevin Prince Boateng-ST-74-74-67-79-82-78-70-83-83
```

You can name this file whatever you like. Make another file in the appropriate location and it will generate everything else needed.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` in every iteration of the inner loop. In general, your code should only ever create one `Random` object, unless multi-threaded or code so big and complex that it's unfeasible,

Comment: Where inicialization of firstShotCount and secondShotCount?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What are the values of `firstShotCount` and `secondShotCount` ?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I fixed this now. I still get the first team always winning.

Comment: *"For some reason `teamOneScored` is ALWAYS higher than `teamTwoScored`"* Could that be because `firstShotCount` is a LOT higher than `secondShotCount`?

Comment: @ZiGaelle they are generated based on the Team. Each team has it's own value. So, often I get a first team with 5 shots and second team with 30+... Still the first wins.

Comment: @Andreas I tested that, but they are predetermined and even when the second shot count is way higher, the first still wins.

Comment: Have you checked if you put the `teamOneScored[i]` and `teamTwoScored[i]` to 0 before the x and y loops ? Doesn't explain why the first will win though

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I ran your code with `depth = 20`, `firstShotCount = 5`, and `secondShotCount = 30`, and didn't get a single result with first > second. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/iRZ3uP) for proof. Perhaps if you wrote a [Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could see what you see.

Comment: @ZiGaelle Yea, I have tested for the passed two hours. I honestly have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: Run with `depth=99`, `firstShotCount=5`, `secondShotCount=30`.  Got 1 case of team one winning, instead of 99 cases of team one winning.  Vote to close - lacks [mcve].

Comment: @AJNeufeld Worked on it, added everything I have. If you need anything else, lmk :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andreas Added it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Guess I should have highlighted another word in that link: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the **minimal** in [mcve].

TL;DR  ... but spotted:

```
int firstDefense = firstPositionAmount[0] + firstPositionAmount[1]/2;
int secondDefense = secondPositionAmount[0] + secondPositionAmount[1]/2;

int firstAttack = firstPositionAmount[2] + firstPositionAmount[1]/2;
int secondAttack = secondPositionAmount[2] + secondPositionAmount[2]/2;
```

Indices are:

```
0 1
0 1
2 1
2 2
```

This seems inconsistent.  Perhaps last should be a 1?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This sent me looking in the right direction :)